# clarification on phar files

Tags: php, phar

I kindly need a clarification on php phar file management as on documentation I did not find what expected.

More in deep I have a simple project like this

```
[main.php]
<?
include_once("./helloworld.php");
helloworld();
?>

[helloworld.php]
<?
function helloworld() {
    echo "Hello World\n";
}
?>
```

Then I've create a phar file with such script:

```
[buildphar.php]
<?
$pharfile = '/home/stefano/test.phar';
if (file_exists($pharfile)) unlink($pharfile);
$phar = new Phar(
   $pharfile,
   FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME,
   "test.phar"
);
$phar->startBuffering();
$phar['main.php'] = php_strip_whitespace("main.php");
$phar['helloworld.php'] = php_strip_whitespace("helloworls.php");
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub("main"));
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

If I distribute [buildphar.php] to another machine and I try to run it

```
php buildphar.php
```

The error given is "Fatal error: function 'helloworld' not found in phar://(...)" and so the question is:
- How can I mantain include_once('helloword.php') but remove them from phar file knowing that's function is embedded on phar file and does not need to be included?
- What's wrong on my approach?

Thanks anyone.
Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you give does not work. Also, distributing `buildphar.php` does not make sense - you probably mean you distribute the `.phar` file.

The problem you're facing (includes do not work) can be solved with [`Phar::interceptFileFuncs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.interceptfilefuncs.php) in the phar stub.